# How to add back to back zeros in python without string?

Tags: python

So this is the question given:
Consider the two lists list1 = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55] and list2 = [66, 77, 88, 99, 00]. How can we join the two list and make it final_list = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 00]

I'm not asking for the answer but when I run the code below I only get one zero at the end?? I can't use a string.
Code:

```
list1 = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
list2 = [66, 77, 88, 99, 00]
final_list= list1+list2
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 0]
```

Comment: you need to format it as a string.

Comment: You cannot get 2 zeros without using a string.

Comment: You can later on print numbers like `print(f'{final_list[i]:02d}')` to print the numbers as two digits

Comment: Just to note, you *are* using a string, you just aren't creating it explicitly. `print` calls `str(final_list)` for you, so you might as well construct the string you want yourself.

Comment: Why can't you use a string? Is this homework? Please check that you understand the problem statement, as this is not possible to do *without* a string.

Comment: (To be precise, it's `int.__repr__`, which `list.__str__` uses to turn each list element into a string, that doesn't add any leading zeros.) (Also, the `int` produced by `00` has no knowledge of how many leading zeros were in the integer literal in the first place.)

Comment: The literals used don't affect the eventual conversion of an `int` back to a string. For example, if you had used hexadecimals like `[0x0b, 0x16, ...]`, the output would still be `[11, 22, ...]`. `int.__repr__` and `int.__str__` produce decimal representations. (`int.__format__`, on the other hand, gives you more flexibility, which is why you need to construct the string yourself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in python, any leading 0 in an `int` will be removed.

You must convert your integer to an `str` if you want to keep the leading 0s.

Comment: Python 3 does not permit leading zeroes in integers. That is because Python 2 used a leading zero to indicate octal, so `010` had the value 8. Python 3 abandoned this octal notation in favour of `0o10`, and so a leading zero in an integer is now a syntax error, to avoid ambiguity. But there is an exception. The interpreter accepts `00`. I suppose that is because it has the value zero no matter what the base.